# Material-UI: How to apply input attributes using TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a couple of input fields (TextField) that I would like to add some aria-* attributes for accessibility.

I am trying this way:

```
const props = {
  InputProps: {
    'aria-label': 'myAriaLabel'
  }
}

// ...

<TextField {...props}></TextField>
```

But Material-UI ends up applying the attribute to the wrapping `div` that is generated. Something like:

```
<div aria-label="myAriaLabel"><input /></div>
```

How can I place this attribute correctly to the `input` element?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need a lowercase i.

`InputProps` are for the `Input` component. `inputProps` are for the `input` element.

https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

Comment: very helpful. Thanks